# Why does node complain about unclosed file descriptors even though I'm closing all my handles?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, filehandle

I have an async function that creates a read stream and writes it to an http response, like so:

```js
    let handle = await getFile();
    let stream = handle.createReadStream();
    let stat = await handle.stat();
    res.setHeader("content-length", stat.size);
    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/octet");
    res.statusCode = 200;
    stream.pipe(res);
    stream.on('close', () => {
      handle.close();
      res.end();
    });
```

As you can see, I close the handle when my stream is closed, and also end the response for good measure. Yet, I see node logging this occasionally:

```
(node:54119) Warning: Closing file descriptor 21 on garbage collection
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:54119) [DEP0137] DeprecationWarning: Closing a FileHandle object on garbage collection is deprecated. Please close FileHandle objects explicitly using FileHandle.prototype.close(). In the future, an error will be thrown if a file descriptor is closed during garbage collection.
```

There are no errors in my HTTP responses and I have verified with a log that my `handle.close()` is getting called for every request. Why does node think that I have unclosed file descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

It was because my async function was returning *before* the stream was done writing. I fixed it by wrapping it with a promise and awaiting it:

```js
    let handle = await getFile();
    let stream = handle.createReadStream();
    let stat = await handle.stat();
    res.setHeader("content-length", stat.size);
    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/octet");
    res.statusCode = 200;
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.pipe(res);
        stream.on('close', () => {
          handle.close();
          res.end();
          resolve();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and on checking the types, I found that `handle.close()` returns a Promise. So even awaiting on `handle.close()` is also a valid approach.

```js
let handle = await getFile();
let stream = handle.createReadStream();
let stat = await handle.stat();

res.setHeader("content-length", stat.size);
res.setHeader("content-type", "application/octet");
res.statusCode = 200;
stream.pipe(res);
stream.on('close', async () => {
  await handle.close();
  res.end();
});
```